# Cumulative Value in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql query as below.

```
SELECT     ColumnTitle AS Months,
                      (SELECT     CellContent
                        FROM          Workflow_CustomFormColumnsData AS CD
                        WHERE      (CustomFormColumnId = Workflow_CustomFormColumns.Id) AND (RowNumber = 1)) AS Planned,
                      (SELECT     CellContent
                        FROM          Workflow_CustomFormColumnsData AS CD
                        WHERE      (CustomFormColumnId = Workflow_CustomFormColumns.Id)    AND (RowNumber = 2)) AS Actual
   FROM         Workflow_CustomFormColumns
   WHERE     (CustomFormId = @CustomForm) AND (ColumnNumber <> 1)
```

I need to have a 4th and 5th Field with cumulative values of Planned and Actual. How do i proceed in this query to reach my goal

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question but maybe what you're looking for is to sum your subqueries and group by ColumnTitle.

```
SELECT ColumnTitle AS Months,
       SUM(SELECT CellContent
           FROM Workflow_CustomFormColumnsData AS CD
           WHERE (CustomFormColumnId = Workflow_CustomFormColumns.Id) 
             AND (RowNumber = 1)) +
       SUM(SELECT CellContent
           FROM Workflow_CustomFormColumnsData AS CD
           WHERE (CustomFormColumnId = Workflow_CustomFormColumns.Id)
             AND (RowNumber = 2))
FROM Workflow_CustomFormColumns
WHERE (CustomFormId = @CustomForm) AND (ColumnNumber <> 1)
GROUP BY ColumnTitle
```

Comment: Hi Mike, my requirement is to create a two fields which contain the cumulative value of the two fields Actual and Planned.

Comment: I updated my answer.  I think you just want to add the two together then.